# IF/AND formula on Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula to compare a couple of cells and return time(Hours and minutes, not a specific time).  Here is the formula that I have come up with:

```
=IF(AND(C18<"24:00",E18>1),"4:30",G18)
```

`C18` = time that may be less than 24:00 hrs or more than 24:00 hrs (ie: 6:30/32:32)
`E18` = a number such as 1 or 2

My goal is: if C18 is less than 24:00hrs but E18 is greater than 1 (ie:2), then display "4:30"(TRUE), else display what is in cell G18(FALSE).

I can't get the formula to come back FALSE when I manipulate C18 but I can when I manipulate E18.  I've tried several different formula formattings but can't seem to make it work.  When I take the "" out from around "24:00", Excel comes back with an error message.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need ??:

```
=IF(AND(C18<1,E18>1),TIMEVALUE("4:30"),G18)
```

since 24 hours corresponds to **1** in Excel.